# Sql function count and sum with Php

Tags: php, sql

I need to get data from my table.
I want only the data of last 24 h , counting the occurrence, with max 60 last infos.

TABLE super_table

```
id username date_post
---------------------
11  james   111105487
10  luke    110105474
9   james   110105400
8   john    111105486
7   james   111100487
6   luke    110105174
5   john    110205474
```

I want something like this

```
james(3)
luke(2)
john(2)
```

Code:

```
<?php
$delay_search=strtotime("+1 day");
$max_user_get=60;
$sql_total = "
SELECT username,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM super_table where date_post <'$delay_search' 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,$max_user_get;
";
$temp='';

$result_total = $conn->query($sql_total);
$nb_total=$result_total->num_rows;
while($row = $result_total->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $username=$row["username"];
    $total_post=$row['count'];  
  
  /*Edit*/
   $temp.='User :'.$username.'('.$total_post.')';

}   
 echo $temp;
?>
```

Comment: So what is your question here? What is not working, where are you stuck? [ask]

Comment: So...what's the issue? Is the query producing what you expected? You don't seem to have wrriten any code to actually display anything...all you're doing is assigning values to $username and $total_post which will get overwritten every time you loop, and which you never actually use. So is your real question about how to echo your data, or something? You only explained the general requirement, not the problem

Comment: Thanks, i've edited. the output records are not the last one of the database. The order by id is not respected, it creates somethings strange.Perhaps due to the timestamp order... The only request that works is : SELECT * FROM super_table where date_post<'$delay_search' order by id desc  LIMIT 0,$max_user_get but it does not count the occurence

Comment: The condition is 24h records and max 60 entries. I know it's hard to explain database without all the code.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the downvote button you can see why downvotes may be given. I personally didn't downvote, but as per the first two comments on the thread, the question was initially quite unclear, which is a legitimate reason to downvote.

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language :)

Comment: `The order by id is not respected`...because it's illegal to use it like that - demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/ulUvn4Y8

Comment: @ADyson id is irrelevant and not needed and it isn't included in the expected result. The OP didn't clarify that, in my opinion

Comment: @ErgestBasha agreed, but they asked for it to be sorted by ID (although that doesn't entirely make sense given it's a grouped result!). I was simply pointing out why that doesn't work in the SQL

Comment: You are right id was not the good way to order. Sorry but the timestamp was not good for the test. It was only for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want only the data of last 24 h

This can be done by from_unixtime to convert the int to date

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(date_post) > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

> counting the occurrence, with max 60 last infos

```
limit 60
```

Final query:

```
select username,
       count(*)
from super_table
where FROM_UNIXTIME(date_post) > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
group by username
order by count(*) desc
limit 60;
```

No need for

```
$delay_search=strtotime("+1 day");
$max_user_get=60;
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm making test and get back.

Comment: Perfect, i've added count(*) AS count to get the total for each username. I've decided to ask on stackoverflow because i've spent 3 hours on this !! Thanks everyone.